# Styling polyline to view which part is above another in self-intersection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, vector-layer

I need to view a polyline constructed from waypoints of a gps track that has self intersections in curves; like an exit loop from a highway.

I need to visualize it in a way that shows which part is above the other in the intersection.

**Option 1: Style with solid color**

This does not work, as the intersection is filled without delimiting the side of the path.

[image]

**Option 2: Style with some predefined road from QGIS**:

Almost doesn't work, as each segment is surrounded by the line, not only at both sides but also in the head and tail of the segment.

[image]

**Option 3: Enabling symbol levels**:

This does not fit my need as it merges the intersections, thus preventing from seeing the precedence.

[image]

I've managed to do the some styling after finding this article in http://planet.qgis.org: http://nathanw.net/2012/07/22/qgis-style-tricks-using-styles-to-help-fix-kerb-line-directions/

The key for me was as easy as using a style of a marker line, with a single triangle marker, and a solid line. Then, I applied transparency so that street names are visible.

This is the result:

[image]

What other option could I try?

Comment: You have a polyline... or a multipolyline?

Comment: It is a polyline layer. I could break the features apart but better if I don't have  to.

Comment: so part of the polyline has to be overlapping itself right? the part that is an  exit loop?

Comment: Yes, question edited for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with option 2, you just need to change the cap style for the line. The pre-defined road style is actually a narrow line on top of a wide line. Change the cap style of the bottom line from round to flat. Now the bottom line doesn't stick out at the end of each segment.

[image]